# Next pointer to another struct Node but declared outside of struct Node

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to make a pointer to a struct that points to the next node of the struct dynamically allocated, usually we put a pointer '*pnext' of the same type of the struct inside the struct, in my case what I would like to do is to put the next pointer to a struct, outside of the struct itself, for instance in main, and point to that pointer with another pointer declared in the same function, how should I do it, and is that possible to do it?

Here's a glance of what it should be supposed to be like in case you didn't get my idea:

```
struct Node{
int data;
};

int main(){
 struct Node *new_node;
 struct Node *next;

 new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
 new_node->data=2;

 new_node->next = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
 new_node->next->data = 3;
 new_node->next = NULL;  /* obviously I cannot do that it was just to make an example of
                            what I would like to do */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That makes no sense. A linked list has multiple nodes, and they each need a `next` pointer so you can tell which are linked to which.

Comment: Your `sizeof` is also wrong. It should be `sizeof(*new_node)`

Comment: If you don't want next-element pointers in your data then you're probably looking for an array.  You're definitely not looking for a linked list.

Comment: is there a way to recognize that next pointer outside of the struct? or is literally impossible?

Comment: If you only have two nodes, you can point to them each with different variables. But the whole point of a linked list is to have an unlimited number of nodes that are chained to each other.

Comment: I fixed sizeof thanks @Barmar, however I'm understanding doing a thing like that would be no more a dynamic list.

Comment: Well you have to have some way to track it, yes there is a way to do it outside however you may have to track the head of the list in the data.,

Comment: @Hynem, if `struct Node` does not contain a member named `next` then your example `new_node->next` subexpressions are 100% invalid.  The only way to rescue those is to make the type to which `new_node` points have such a member, either by modifying the definition of that type or by assigning a different, more suitable type.

Comment: can you answer WHY you want to track it outside? is it because you want to have multiple types of lists of the same data?

Comment: @Hynem Exactly, it's not any kind of list. It's just two unrelated structures.

Comment: @AhmedMasud I want to make a regular dynamic list, and track each nodes of the list from a next pointer declared outside, the reason why, well I'm just curious if I can do that that's all.

Comment: But that's just it, @Hynem: you cannot track *each* element of a multi-element linked list with just *one* `next` pointer.  Not in any language.  It's not a question of syntax: one pointer provides information about one object (specifically, the address of that object) .  You need to maintain information about multiple objects, so one pointer cannot be sufficient.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be a pointer in your structure to hold the address of next node. You cannot store it in main outside your structure.